# MVC - display a user profile setting in dropdown list on several pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I would like to display the value of a specific user profile setting in the header of every page (_Layout.cshtml). I see how a default MVC Web Application displays the user's name in "Welcome user!", but this name is obtained by calling `User.Identity.GetUserName()`. The setting I want to display is a custom setting.

It would seem that I need to pass the custom setting from the controller, but I'm not sure how to get to the controller from within _Layout.cshtml. I've tried @Html.RenderPartial, but that doesn't trigger a Controller Action/method, or can it?

I've tried @Html.RenderAction which gets me into the controller, that requires an entire View to be rendered, or is there a way around this?

Could someone tell me what razor syntax I would use from any view to trigger a Controller Action that will render just an input control? I don't need the Controller/Action logic other than the return statement.

**EDIT**

@Rowan Freeman seems to be pointing me back in a direction that I already tried. In fairness he didn't know I need to perform a POST with this user setting. Here is the code I've tried:

**ViewModel**

```
public class LanguageListPartialViewModel
{
    public string SelectedLanguage { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> Languages { get; set; }
}
```

**~/Views/Shared/_LanguageListPartial.cshtml**

```
@model GPS_Web_App.Models.LanguageListPartialViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedLanguage,
    Model.Languages,
    new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "this.form.submit();" }
)
```

**~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml**

```
<form action="/Account/LanguageListPartial" method="post">
    @{Html.RenderAction("LanguageListPartial", "Account");} 
</form>
```

**GET Controller Action**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult LanguageListPartial()
{
    // Logic to create a populate model's List<SelectListItem> Languages 
    // Logic to set model's string SelectedLanguage
    // Logic is already written and returns correct list.

    return PartialView("_LanguageListPartial", model);
}
```

**POST Controller Action**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> LanguageListPartial(string SelectedLanguage)
{
    // Logic to set user profile setting to selection
    // Logic is already written and correctly sets user profile setting

    return RedirectToLocal(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath);
}
```

The reason I wrap the partial view with  in _Layout.cshtml is because there are times when I only want to display the list within a form on a different page - for example, EditProfile page - it contains it's own  wrapper. I do have one caveat, that is that the PartialView has an onSubmit() which has the undesirable effect of submitting any form it's contained it. I'll fix that later.

The problem with the above layout seems to be specifically with the return() in the POST action - the rendered page on return consists only of the dropdown list instead of rendering the dropdown list within the page it was called from.

Comment: Why not extend the `User / Identity` object?

Comment: How complicated is that? I can get my setting from ApplicationUser, of course, but it doesn't seem like best practice to be including the ApplicationUser in every page on a site.

Comment: Extension methods are relatively simple.

Answer (score 1):

**Use `Html.Action` in conjunction with a partial view.**

You're very close to a good solution. Let me clarify the steps.

1. **Create a partial view.** A partial view is just a regular view but they're usually small and are used to be **part** of the final page to be rendered. The partial view might be called *"_UserProfile.cshtml"*. An underscore at the beginning is a good convention for indicating a partial view. The view should use a simple model, perhaps `UserProfileModel`.
2. **Create an appropriate controller and action.** The controller could be called `PartialsController` and the action might be `UserProfile()`. Attach the attribute `[ChildActionOnly]` to the action (or controller) so that it can't be accessed by a regular URL. The action should `return PartialView("_UserProfile");`.
3. **Call the action** from your `_Layout` using `@Html.Action("UserProfile", "Partials")`.

Comment: I have attempted it this way, but the control also allows the user to change the setting (it's a language dropdown). My problem was that the POST action seemed to want to return a view that consisted only of the dropdown list. I'll update my question to include my code. I think it's pretty much what you recommend and it works except for on the POST action.

Comment: I edited my question. Does your suggestion still have merit? I was going to abandon this route because it just doesn't work like I need. I would really like to get rid of the redirect.